# how to convert one string seperated by commas into individual strings (python)

Tags: python

how can i change this.

```
a= ['man, boy, mum']
```

into

```
a=['man', 'boy', 'mum']
```

I have tried replacing the commas with (') but it does not work.
any help will be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried or *researched*? Tip: The `str` type has a method for handling exactly this.  I'll even throw you a bone and link the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for you.  Have a look down this list and find the method for splitting a string into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick answer for you

```
>>> a = ['man, boy, mun']
>>> result = a[0].split(',')
>>> result
['man', ' boy', ' mun']
```

Now you need to clean up the white spaces (' ').

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
a = a[0].split(",")
```

Comment: Than you get spaces in front of words.

Comment: You can use a = [x.replace(" ","") for x in a] to get rid of the white spaces